# Getting 'Bind variables only allowed in Apex code' when attempting this query

Tags: soql

```
SELECT Id, Last_stage_changed_date__c, CreatedDate 
FROM Opportunity 
WHERE Last_stage_changed_date__c < CreatedDate
```

`Last_stage_changed_date__c` is of the `Date` type. I feel like I'm doing something dumb but I can't spot it.

Getting the error:

> Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

Comment: Seems a weird query logically: surely CreatedDate comes before any other date?

Comment: I was trying to use this query to fix a bug where this is the case

Comment: Fair enough. I'd add the formula, fix the data, then remove the formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare one field to another in SOQL, regardless of context. If you want to compare a custom date field to `CreatedDate`, you will need a separate checkbox formula field to do the comparison for you, then you can filter on this field being true.

Take a look at the documentation on [fieldExpression Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> fieldName comparisonOperator value
> ```
>
> value: A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field. You must supply a native value—**other field names or calculations are not permitted**. If quotes are required (for example, they are not for dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Apex code in that case? I don't want to create any additional fields if I don't have to.

Comment: Nope. Unless you want to query every record in the system and then post-process. No matter what your context, comparing one field to another is not supported, except by adding a formula.